# How to use history server in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have logged one of my jobs in Apache Spark using the following snippet in the Universities.

```
  conf = SparkConf()\
         .setAppName("Ex").set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")\
         .set("spark.eventLog.dir", "log")
```

After the job has completed, I tried to copy the log file `app-20170416171823-0000`. On to my local system and tried to follow the following command to go through the recorded Spark Web UI.

```
sbin/start-history-server.sh ~/Downloads/log/app-20170416171823-0000
```

But the history terminated with the following error:

```
failed to launch: nice -n 0 /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer /Users/sk/Downloads/log/app-20170416171823-0000      at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:77)     ... 6 more full log in /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/logs/spark-sk-org.apa
```

che.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-Sk-MacBook-Pro.local.out

Contents of the output of the history server:

```
17/04/16 17:44:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/04/16 17:44:52 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(skaran); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(skaran); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$.main(HistoryServer.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.main(HistoryServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Logging directory specified is not a directory: file:/Users/sk/Downloads/log/app-20170416171823-0000
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$FsHistoryProvider$$startPolling(FsHistoryProvider.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.initialize(FsHistoryProvider.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.<init>(FsHistoryProvider.scala:77)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the argument should be the folder containing the log.

Comment: Tried that with no success